# Use Excel VBA to update data in SQL Server via ADODB

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula, vba

In Excel **Sheet1**, data is pulled from an SQL Server:

```
code   Name
1      ALI
2      SALEM
```

I want update data with vba not from a full SQL query
 to replace  name ALI to Ahmed

Is there a way to do this?  Does Excel give me a way to make the update without sending an SQL query?

**Some information:**

```
**TABEL Name** = Tb1
**colmun1** = code(in excel)   = Emp_code (sql)
**colmun2** = Name(in excel)   = E_name   (sql)
```

**server name**: HHsqlexpress

Comment: This question isn't very clear.  Perhaps you could rewrite us and tell us where the data is currently stored, how you want to change it, and what specific issue you are running into.

Comment: the data is stored on SQL >> i need make it update or insert data from vba excel

Comment: And what are you using?  ODBC?  ADODB?  OleDB?

Comment: Im using ' ADODB '

Comment: Does that edit help?

Comment: If the question is 'how do I update changes in excel back to a database' the answer is: use an `UPDATE` query. If for some reason you can't use an update query you could use an ADO `Recordset` instead, which is just different (more complicated) code to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this VBA via ADODB Code >>> if any modified or add

```
Private Sub UpdateSQLData()
On Error GoTo err
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql_string As String
Dim strconn As String

DataBaseName = "----"
ServerName = "196.1.1.1/SSDDSDS"
UserId = "ADMIN"
Password = "123"

strconn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=" & Password & ";User ID=" & UserId & ";Initial Catalog=" & DataBaseName & ";Data Source=" & ServerName
sql_string = "update transactions set CustomerID='2'  where amount =1000 "
cn.Open strconn
rs.Open sql_string, cn


Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close

Exit Sub
err:
MsgBox err.Description
End Sub
```